# search hash by value in ruby is returning nil

Tags: ruby

Im trying to search this hash by the value of :user

```
cache = {
  {:user=>1}=>{:last_visit=>2014-01-25 09:22:42 -0800, :frequency=>0},
  {:user=>2}=>{:last_visit=>2014-01-25 09:22:43 -0800, :frequency=>0},
  {:user=>3}=>{:last_visit=>2014-01-25 09:22:43 -0800, :frequency=>0}
}
```

I tried a number things including below but I always get nil

```
new_user = cache.select{|key, hash| hash[:user] == user }

new_user = cache.invert[:user=>user]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean of `#invert`? what wish you do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do as below

```
cache = {{:user=>1}=>{:last_visit=>'2014-01-25 09:22:42 -0800', :frequency=>0}, {:user=>2}=>{:last_visit=>'2014-01-25 09:22:43 -0800', :frequency=>0}, {:user=>3}=>{:last_visit=>'2014-01-25 09:22:43 -0800', :frequency=>0}}
cache.select{|key_hash,value_hsh| key_hash[:user] == 2 }
# => {{:user=>2}=>{:last_visit=>"2014-01-25 09:22:43 -0800", :frequency=>0}}
```

Your `cache` hash has keys and values, where keys are also hash and values are also hash. The symbol `:user` is a key of the key hash(s) of your `cache` hash. In your code `cache.select{|key, hash| hash[:user] == user }`, you were searching the key `:user`, in value hash, instead of a key hash.

Now as per the documentation [`Hash#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) -

> Element Reference—Retrieves the value object corresponding to the key object. If not found, returns `nil`( if not default value is set, otherwise that default value).

So in your case `hash[:user]` always returned `nil`. Thus `cache.select { .. }` always returned empty array.